# Ample vector bundles, $H^1=0$ and global generation in characteristic $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-p

This is a follow up from [Ample vector bundles on curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49644/ample-vector-bundles-on-curves) question, in characteristic $p>0$. First, some background. It is known that in characteristic $0$, a vector bundle $E$ on say a projective curve $X$ is ample if and only if every quotient bundle has positive degree. This is known as Hartshorne's Theorem (see [Hartshorne - Ample vector bundles on curves](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-43/issue-none/Ample-vector-bundles-on-curves/nmj/1118798366.full) and [Hartshorne - Ample vector bundles](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1966__29__63_0)) which is known (due to Serre, see the first linked paper) to fail in positive characteristic $p$. Serre's example deals with a smooth quartic $X/\mathbb{F}_3$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, i.e. a curve of genus $3$ and the construction goes as follows:

Let $X$ be given by the equation $x^3y+y^3z+z^3x=0$. One proves that the action of Frobenius $F:X\to X$ on $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is trivial (i.e. the Hasse–Witt matrix is identically zero). One then constructs a rank $2$ bundle which is a non-trivial extension: $0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \to E \to \mathcal{O}_X(p) \to 0$ for $p\in X$ such that pulling back by Frobenius trivialises the extension $F^*E = \mathcal{O}_X \oplus \mathcal{O}_X(3p)$ (note $F^*\mathcal{O}(p) = \mathcal{O}(3p)$) and also every quotient line bundle of $E$ has positive degree. Then it's a lemma that $F^*E$ is ample iff $E$ is and we know $F^*E$ is not ample since it has $\mathcal{O}_X$ as a quotient which is not ample.

[Edit: As pointed out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69806/ample-vector-bundles-h1-0-and-global-generation-in-characteristic-p#comment176455_69806), in this example, $E$ is not globally generated as it has a degree $1$ quotient.] My question is whether there is a counterexample to Hartshorne's theorem which is globally generated or if one can hope to prove ampleness using Hartshorne's theorem for a bundle in characteristic $p$ assuming global generation and vanishing $H^1$.

Original motivation: I am studying curves $f:C\to X$ in characteristic $p$ such that $H^1(C, f^*T_X) = 0$ and $f^*T_X$ is globally generated (aka free curves à la Kollàr) and was wondering whether these two conditions are enough to prove that $f^*T_X$ is ample. In characteristic $0$, if one assumes that the genus of $C$ is $\geq2$ then only the cohomology vanishing is enough to deduce the result (as shown at an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/49656) to [Ample vector bundles on curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49644/ample-vector-bundles-on-curves)). Can one show ampleness by making the extra assumption (or not!) of global generation in characteristic $p$?

Comment: Just to clarify: in your first paragraph, should X already be a curve?

Comment: Apologies yes, fixed.

Comment: It is clear that $E$ as above is not globally generated, since $\mathcal{O}_X(p)$ being a degree one line bundle on genus 3 curve can not be globally generated.

Comment: Of course, thank you! I suppose this leaves the question whether global generation can play a role in the existence of a counter-example